# how to know gcm has successfully sent notification to device?

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

The server is using php and sends gcm notification via http. We added logs on the php so we are sure that a gcm notification is generated and was sent. But how do we know that the device actually received the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) alone would not be able to do this. For such scenario, your client(device) should send ACK to server. When device receives notification, use HTTP request to send message to server side about notification being received. You could pass in device id in the request in order to identify the device that received notification.

Comment: So the 'success' from GCM response does not guarantee that the message will be delivered?

Comment: @user3759156 yes, success response on your server side from GCM DOES NOT guarantee successful message delivery, but it just means that the message was accepted for delivery